# Grow hydroponics on fleece

Tags: indoors, hydroponic, growing-medium

I would like to grow plants in an indoor garden on fleece mats like used in this video: [Aero Farms indoor growing](https://youtu.be/-_tvJtUHnmU?t=65) . Where can I find these "reusable cloth"? They should be suitable form multiple growing periodes.

When I looked this up online, I could only find products that prevent plants from growing thrue. Does anyone have experience with this and can give me some tips?

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea. You'll have to be careful buying. [Fleece](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fleece): "the coat of wool covering a wool-bearing animal (such as a sheep)." There's a lot of "fiber fill" out there these days. Usually made from some water repelling strands. *None* that I've seen (wife makes pillows/quilts) will soak up water the way you want. Quilts used to come with wool fleece, when people used them to stay warm at night instead of hanging them on a wall.
Looks like "[fleece fabric](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fleece%20fabric&t=ffsb)" will get you sources of what you want. Not sure what country you are in, so I can't begin to make a recommendation. Check the descriptions carefully to ensure that you are ordering washed, felted wool, or at least untreated cotton. It might be best to give the company a call before ordering, as there *lots* of hydrophobic synthetics sold for "fleece". That is *not* what you want. The stuff has got to get soggy (hydrophillic).
For durability, wool is a better choice than cotton.